# c++ memory leak or not

Tags: c++, memory, syntax

i have code:

```
class foo
{
public:
  bar(const QString& s){}
.....
};

int main()
{
 .....
 foo f;
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     f.bar(QString("%1").arg(i));
 ....
 return 0;
}
```

I have memory leak on string "f(QString("some string text?"));" or not?

Another example

```
class foo
{
  QUdpSocket socket;
public:
  foo();  
  void send_msq();
};

foo::foo(){
  socket.bind(QHostAddress("192.168.20.1"),50501);
}

void send_msq()
{
  socket.writeDatagram(...);
}
```

I have any problem on string "socket.bind(QHostAddress("192.168.20.1"),50501);" ?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. I'd work on that first.

Comment: Probably not. `QString` is meant to keep track of its own memory and you are just passing a copy. I assume that `foo` has a member of `xxx operator()(QString const&)`.

Comment: Did you mean f.bar(QString("some string text?")); ?

Comment: Please post real code. Don't type from memory.

Comment: grieve, thanks.  Kerrek SB real code is wery big.

Comment: There's still a spurious & in the declaration of `bar`. Did you mean `bar(QString &s)`? Which still wouldn't compile because you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: @k_zaur_k: Doesn't have to be your full application.  Just post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no memory leak. The `QString` class manages its own memory (assuming you are talking about this [`QString`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html).

You are creating a temporary of that class, which is destroyed when the call to `foo::bar` returns. At that point, the destructor is run, freeing any memory held by the `QString` class.

In general, as long as your resources are managed by classes, and you are not allocating them with `new`, you don't need to worry about freeing resources, as the destructor will run when the class instance goes out of scope.

When you use `new`, or use resource whose lifetime isn't managed by a class (like memory returned by `malloc` or a file returned by `fopen` (as opposed to `fstream`, which is a class and cleans up when it is destroyed)), that's when you need to make sure to clean it up.

The best way to do that, incidentally, is to wrap such resources in a class that manages the resource's lifetime through the constructor and destructor, and then use that class instead of the "raw" resource; this is known as the [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) pattern.